# Views created progmatically aren't inheriting theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to create a view pragmatically and then add it to my activity. This bit is working fine, however the theme for the view group isn't inherited by my new view

My theme:

```
<style name="CustomButtonTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
  <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
  <item name="android:background">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/CustomButtonTheme">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This button inherits CustomButtonTheme" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(getContext());
button.setText("This button does not inherit CustomButtonTheme");

LinearLayout buttonArea = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.buttonArea);
buttonArea.addView(button);
```

Comment: That `theme` attribute in your layout will only have effect during inflation. It won't be applied to your `Activity`'s overall theme. All it does, however, is cause the `LayoutInflater` wrap its current `Context` with a `ContextThemeWrapper`. You can do the same; e.g., `ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.CustomButtonTheme);`, `... new AppCompatButton(wrapper);`.

Comment: I just realized that there's a simpler way. Use the `LinearLayout`'s `Context` to create the `AppCompatButton`; i.e., `... new AppCompatButton(buttonArea.getContext());`. No need for your own separate `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Comment: This is perfect! The second method has the added benefit that I don't need to hard code the theme in the context wrapper. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it on here to give you the well deserved credit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `android:theme` attribute in a layout will only have effect during inflation, and only on that particular subtree. It won't be applied to the `Activity`'s overall theme.

All that attribute does, though, is cause the `LayoutInflater` to wrap its current `Context` with the specified theme in a `ContextThemeWrapper`. We could do something similar ourselves, and just to illustrate the basic usage:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.CustomButtonTheme);
AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(wrapper);
```

However, this has already been done for us, basically, when the `LayoutInflater` created a `ContextThemeWrapper` internally, for that `android:theme` attribute. That `ContextThemeWrapper` is the `Context` that the `LinearLayout` will have been created with, so we can simply use its `Context` to instantiate our `AppCompatButton`:

```
AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(buttonArea.getContext());
```

As the OP points out, this has the added benefit of working in pretty much every similar setup without having to know the exact theme needed.